# Reading fasta files and edit the lines in python

Tags: python, sequence, edit

i'm new in programming and its the first time i use python. I'm working on a code that should read a fasta file and delete the header of each sequence.
My code to read the file:

```
def read_fasta(inputfile):
    with open(inputfile,'r') as f:
        file=f.readlines()
    f.close
    return file

fasta_file=read_fasta('SELEX_100_reads.txt')

print(fasta_file)
```

The output of fasta file looks like that:

```
['@DBV2SVN1:110:B:7:1101:1456:2092\n', 'CTAAAAAGCGAGTGCGNCNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNANNNNNNCNNNNNNNNAAACANNAAGGTAAGAAACAAGCACAGATGAGAGC\n', '\n', '+\n', '#####################################################################################################\n', '\n', '@DBV2SVN1:110:B:7:1101:2491:2141\n', 'AAGTGAGCAAACAGAAACATAGTGCGGAGTGGGAAAATGAGACTCAAAAAAAGAGTGTGGGTATTCAGTAGGGGATATTAGGCCACAATACGAAAGAGCAA\n', '\n', '+\n', '#####################################################################################################\n', '\n', '@DBV2SVN1:110:B:7:1101:2924:2130\n'......]
```

it's a list with header for each sequence. therefore i just want the DNA sequences (CTAAAA or AAGTAAAGCA) of each line as a list.
Can anyone help me with that ?
Thanks a lot

Cheers,
John

Comment: Please fix the code. You dont need `f.close` if you are using `with open` context manager. Also `f.close` is not even called. You can remove that line.

Comment: Thats my new code: 

def read_fasta(inputfile):
    with open(inputfile,'r') as f:
        file=f.readlines()
       
        for elem in file:
            if elem !='@':
                file.remove(elem)
        return file

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can filter the DNA into a new list:

```
only_dna = fasta_file[1::6]
```

In [1::6], the 1 is the starting position and the 6 is the "skip interval" in the list.

Comment: Hello Danise, thanks for your help. It helped me a lot.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a regex filter.  Assuming that you just want lines that contain only one or more A/C/G/T or N characters (aside from newline and any other trailing whitespace), you could do:

```
import re

file = list(filter(re.compile("[ACGTN]+\s*$").match, file))
```

to remove the other lines.

If strings containing N are not meant to be included (I don't know enough biochemistry to know what they represent - not a nucleotide by the looks of things), then obviously exclude the `N` from the regexp.

Comment: Hello alaniwi, thanks for your help. A good approach and method. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

- From the question i think what you want is all the lines which are DNA sequence.
- You can filter lines if they contain anythting other than A,C,G,T.

```py
def read_fasta(inputfile):
    with open(inputfile,'r') as f:
        file=f.readlines()
    ret = []
    for line in file:
        if set(strip(line)) == {'A','G','T','C'}:
            ret.append(strip(line)) 
    return ret 

fasta_file=read_fasta('SELEX_100_reads.txt')

print(fasta_file)
```